# Is there a software for viewing changes in objects in the JVM heap memory in real time?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, trace

Imagine that you have a running Java application and you want to check what object properties a button click changes and where in the JVM heap memory. In a small program you could debug the click step by step but if it is a very large program this might take a lot of time. So is there a JVM monitor that can record and show the changes in heap after an event like this. I know I can make a heap dump before and after the event and then compare, but I am asking if there is a more intelligent way. Something like RegMon or Filemon for Windows but for the Java JVM. Thank you :)

Comment: profiler tool like jvisualvm, jprofiler

Comment: Read about MBeans: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually taking heap dumps 'is' the intelligent way, as one must understand that (especially in GUI frameworks) a click will change a lot more than just the button parameters.

There is a lot of stuff involved in this.
You may want to use the inbuilt Eclipse debugger, which allows you to track changes in particular variables, as well as whole objects.

If you're more interested in internals I can recommend jvisualvm which is bundled by default in jdk. It will attach to a hotspot JVM instance to monitor its internals.

Alternatively:

- http://visualvm.java.net/ - A multi tool for general JVM tracing.
- https://eclipse.org/mat/ - Brilliant memory analyzer, which can for instance take two two heap dumps, and clearly show you what has changed <<--- **probably what you're looking for**

Comment: Thank you for your reply! By a "more intelligent way" I meant without recording the entire heap memory to a file. If there was a way to filter the monitoring to just a certain group of objects it would be very convenient to have the changed objects light up in a different color. I will try the eclipse tool :)

Comment: @Alex that's exactly what the debugger does :)

Comment: In my case I have some very messed up and complex code. I just want to see what ends up different without looking through the code. Then I can put meaningful breakpoints and debug more efficiently :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use heap dumps and try to learn those heap dumps, as suggested by Jitsu.

Other ways are:

[Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/): 
Java heap analyzer that helps you find memory leaks and reduce memory consumption

[VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) & JConsole: It provides nice UI to analyse your jvm memory

[JStat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstat.html): It is a java virtual machine statistics and monitoring tool

[Netbeans Profiler](https://profiler.netbeans.org/): Available along with Netbeans, which gives you profiling of your application

[JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html): This is a paid tool which will give you more insights in to java application profiling to analyze memory.

[FusionReactor](https://www.fusion-reactor.com/ultimate-edition/): Another paid for tool which provides real-time insights into java applications running in production environments to profile code, memory and threads.